# React Native ComponentDidMount not loading

Tags: react-native

the `ComponentDidMount` function in my React Native project doesn't seem to be running for some reason. Recently I tried adding a search function to my code, and after I implemented the features the function seemed to be not working. So I tried to remove the new features and still the function isn't running.

Here is the code, perhaps I'm missing something.

```
export default class CategoryScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
        this.state={
      data : [],
      isVisible: true,
      city : '280',
      isLoading: true,
      searched: ''
    }
  }
async componentDidMount() {
    let id = this.props.navigation.state.params.category
    let city = this.state.city
    let result;
    try {
        console.log('check1')
      result = await axios.request({
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?city_id=${city}&q=${searched}&category=${id}`,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'user-key': "a31bd76da32396a27b6906bf0ca707a2",
        },
      })
    } catch (err) {
      err => console.log(err)
    }
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      data: result.data.restaurants
    })
    console.log('check2')
  }
render() {
    return ()
}
}
```

when I run the project the terminal shows `check1` however `check2` doesn't show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the final part of your code into a `finally {...}` block, which will execute after `try` completes successfully or - if catch is triggered - the `catch` block is complete.

One thing to note: since you have no initial value for `result`, if your try block throws an error then you will get *another* error when you try to setState using `result.data.restaurants`, since `data` won't exist.

I think the cleanest way to resolve this would be to split out setState into two. Only setting `data` if you have a result:

```js
    async componentDidMount() {
      try {
        const id = this.props.navigation.state.params.category;
        const city = this.state.city;
        
        console.log('check1');
        
        const result = await axios.request({
          method: 'get',
          url: `https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?city_id=${city}&q=${searched}&category=${id}`,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'user-key': 'a31bd76da32396a27b6906bf0ca707a2'
          }
        });
    
        this.setState({ data: result.data.restaurants }); // only triggers if your axios request worked
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err); // remove the erroneous `err =>`
      } finally {
        // add this finally block
        this.setState({ isLoading: false }); // now only set isLoading once everything is complete
        console.log('check2');
      }
    }
```

Note, also changed your `let` declarations to `const` since you don't reassign them (and shouldn't!), and moved them into only the required scope.

Comment: this code was really really helpful! it also helped terminal output an error that my previous code wasn't! Thank you so much